# How should I name the EJB to lookup it correctly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I have a simple problem, I have a Stateless EJB bean running in Glassfish 4. I have a client, and I want to lookup for this ejb, and I simply cannot make the right name. How should I name these correctly to work?

I just got `javax.naming.NamingException`, but I have no clue how to do it right.
I follow the `java:global/[ear-name]/[jar-name]/[ejb-name]![fully-qualified-interface-name]` convention.

Here is the client:

```
...
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calculator;
        Context ctx = null;

        try {
            Properties environment = new Properties();
            environment.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
            environment.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

            // Find the EJB with a JNDI lookup
            ctx = new InitialContext(environment);
            calculator = (Calculator)ctx.lookup(
                "java:global/calculator-application/calculator-ejb/calcBean!eak.Calculator"
            );
        } catch(NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }           
        ...
    }
}
```

Here are the annotations of my EJB component:

```
@Stateless(name="calcBean", mappedName="calc")
@Remote(Calculator.class)
public class CalculatorBean implements Calculator {
...
```

And I run what jndi names are in my Glassfish server:

```
C:\javaee\glassfish4\glassfish\bin>asadmin.bat list-jndi-entries
UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.startup.TransactionLifecycleServ
ice$2
ejb: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
java:global: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
calc__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__: javax.naming.Reference
calc: javax.naming.Reference
jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
concurrent: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager: com.sun.enterpris
e.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl
jms: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
calc#eak.Calculator: javax.naming.Reference
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
```

Comment: Have you tried `calc#eak.Calculator` from your output above?

Comment: If you use the GlassFish application client container, and package your client application in your .ear as a &lt;java&gt; module, your entire code example can be reduced to just one line: `@EJB Calculator calculator;`

Comment: do you package in .ear or in .war?

Answer (score 2):

You'r configuration looks valid to me. I tested your example and it worked just fine. Please make sure that the `gf-client.jar` from `glassfish4/glassfish/lib` is in your classpath. Please also confirm that your application, module and bean names are as you see in the Glassfish console. In my case JNDI lookup string `java:global/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-ejb-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT/calcBean!Echo` worked perfectly.

[image]